# Unity3D Rotation not behaving as expected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I am trying to make a small demo for a simulation and I thought this part was going to be easy. Boy was I wrong and now I am totally stuck. Here is my problem.

I am trying to work with rotation and for this issue we will work with a 30 degree angle which is shown below:

[image: The green ray is -15 degrees, red is 0 degrees and blue is +15 degrees for a total of 30 degrees.]

The green ray is -15 degrees, red is 0 degrees and blue is +15 degrees for a total of 30 degrees.

Now I want to divide said 30 degrees into equalish parts so the first good number would be 10. meaning I can draw a ray every 3 degrees until I hit my maximum which in this case is +15 degrees. This can be seen below:

[image: Looks good! There is a small amount of space that is off and if anyone knows why that is please let me know.]

Looks good! There is a small amount of space that is off and if anyone knows why that is please let me know.

Now, I need a large amount of rays so we are going to go up by a factor of 10 and increase the number of divisions to 100 which can be seen below. Also I need to use imgur because there are only two pictures allowed here so please bear with me and thank you.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqfZy.jpg

The first picture is with 100 chunks and as you can see the rays are all cast to the left. That is a problem.

The second picture is with the divisions increased to 1000. Even worse now is the fact that the got all the way around the object except for a 15 degree area.

Here is the snippet that is doing this.

```
 if(testRotation)   
 {
      //Sets the objects rotation to the starting rotation which is -15 degeres
      this.transform.Rotate(this.transform.rotation.x, this.transform.rotation.y - 15.0f,           
           this.transform.rotation.z);

      for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
      {
           //Draws a ray at the current position and forwards relative to the objects transform
           Debug.DrawRay(this.transform.position, 
           this.transform.forward * maxSightDistance, Color.cyan, 1000.0f);

           //This advances the rotation by a factor of one chunk 
           //which in this case is 10 which seems to work 
           this.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(this.transform.rotation.x, 
           this.transform.rotation.y + (30/10), this.transform.rotation.z));
      }

      //This makes it so it doesn't run forever
      testRotation = false;

 }
```

The only places that change are in the for loop where the conditional is checked and also the second parameter of the Rotate function which adds to the current rotational value by "one chunk".

For 100 chunks I modify the pieces to: `for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)` and `this.transform.rotation.y + (30/100)`

For 1000 chunks I modify the pieces to: `for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)` and `this.transform.rotation.y + (30/1000)`

I am totally stuck and don't know why it's is doing what it's doing. Also if you need something explained or clarified please let me know !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dividing a number by an integer, which will return an integer. You instead need to divide by a float to return a decimal number.
i.e.

```
this.transform.rotation.y + (30/100f)
this.transform.rotation.y + (30/1000f)
```

Edit: Additionally, the components of rotate should be 0 instead of their previous value to avoid accumulation of rotation.

```
transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 30/10f, 0));
```

Comment: So this solves the problem for 100 segments but dividing by 1000 still does the ring wrapping around

Comment: I totally understood what you meant and I added that for both cases but the 1000 segments even in float form still gibe that ring of rays around the object with the rays missing in the spot they should be showing up.

Comment: What happens if you put smaller numbers like 200 or 500 in?

Comment: When 200 is put in the rays get tighter but they stop before the 0 degree line. When 500 is put in it starts to go around like 1000 does but not as far. From what I can tell, the small the divisions get the rotation starts to go negative?

Comment: If you put 0 in for the x and z component within the for-loop in the `this.transform.Rotate(new Vector3()` does it act any differently?

Comment: Further analysis: The rays are cast in a positive fashion meaning to the right of the -15 degree line all the way up to 229 segment divisions. From 230 divisions and beyond they go to the left of the -15 degree line.

Comment: Putting 0.0f for both x and z in the Rotate function did not change the behavior.

Comment: Wow I am really out of it today. This was fixed by palcing 0.0f in all three parameters. So it should be this.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f + 30/1000f, 0.0f));